# PHP dynamic function call

Tags: php

I'm not so sure about how I should ask this question but I'll try to make it clear :

I have document.php and doc2.php (for example).

In the first one, I want to put a function in a variable so that I'll be able to say in the first one :

```
   $_SESSION['action'] = 'exampleFunction($params)';
```

In the second document, I'd love to be able to say :

```
   $params = 'test';
   $_SESSION['action'];
```

It would then be possible for me to launch the right function depending on what the user does in the previous document.

Comment: This sounds more like a design issue. I'm trying to imagine a case where you would need to store a function within the session. Can you elaborate a little more on what you are trying to do?

Comment: sounds like an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem

Comment: Have a mapping of actions to functions, or `require` a file, or… it really depends on the situation.

Comment: Agreed, this sounds like something that should be done some other way.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look into [OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "variable functions"

```
<?php
function foo() {
    echo "In foo()<br />\n";
}

$func = 'foo';
$func('arg1');
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks you very much you saved me alot of time ! Didnt knew about it, PHP is awesome eheh

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `create_function()`.

[Reference.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)

Answer (score -1):

You can use eval function: http://www.php.net/manual/function.eval.php

```
eval($_SESSION['action']);
```

But i strongly discourage to do so, because it's dangerously insecure

Comment: @Rafael There are many better, more secure alternatives to `eval` in this situation.

Comment: @DC_, Thanks, i agree, and that's why i stated that is dangerously insecure, but it's definitely a valid solution.

Comment: by that logic, amputation of the arm is a valid solution to a sore thumb.

Comment: @Dagon, If it's due it being grangenated, it is a valid solution. :-)

Comment: I gave upvote because I'm personally sick of listening to "eval is insecure/dangerous, discouraged..." stories without any valid explanation why. Eval is nothing more/less then evaluation of your code as string; that means if you suck in writing code without any touch with eval at all, you suck with using eval also, only difference is is lack of comfort when code in eval needs to be debugged. AND FOR GOD SAKE, eval() construct is implied when calling to require() or include() - so, if you're PHP coder , you are using eval() on a regular basis.